# Почему массив $_POST остается пустым?

Tags: post, битрикс

Какие могут быть причины у того, то после отправки формы в $_POST - пусто? И как найти эти причины?

```
<form method="post" action="<?=$arParams['CONFIRM_URL']?>" name="regform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Это строка из темплейта компонента битикса. Вот после отправки этой формы в ПОСТ ничего нет.

Comment: хоть и не в битриксе, а в `cakephp` под IIS было недавно пустой request когда размер файла превышал максимальный размер загружаемого файла в настройках php.ini (2Мбайт по умолчанию).

Comment: а так убедитесь сначала в Инструментах браузера, что запрос точно отправляется с нужными данными, т.е. что они точно уходят на сервер в нужном составве

Comment: то что вы добавили заголовок формы ничего не говорит о том, что там вообще отправляется внутри, а только говорит нам, что форма действительно должна отправляться методом `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST может быть пустым из-за CSRF-защиты.

```
<form method="post" action="<?=$arParams['CONFIRM_URL']?>" name="regform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- другие поля -->
    <?=bitrix_sessid_post();?>
</form>
```